# GET request $filter on field in a 'Detail' versus 'Top-Level'

Tags: acumatica

I am developing a series of requests using Acumatica's REST API to be used in an Ecommerce integration. This particular example I wanted to get all items that had an onhand quantity.

> /entity/Default/17.200.001>/PhysicalInventoryCount?$filter=PhysicalInventoryCountDetail/PhysicalQty gt 1

And received the following error:

> "message": "An error has occurred.",
>
> "exceptionMessage": "The given key was not present in the dictionary.",

Just to be sure I wasn't doing something wrong I went ahead and used the example shown in the acumatica help for the $filter parameter:

> /entity/Default/17.200.001/Customer?$filter=MainContact/Email eq >'barkeep@usabartend.con'

And this in fact did bring up the correct customer record

'MainContact' is listed as a an object type 'Top-Level' of 'Customer' while 'PhysicalInventoryCountDetail' has an object type of 'Detail', is it simply that I cannot filter on a detail object field? Or is there something I am missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not filter by details. It is not supported. 
You can filter by linked entities (and it works in your example with filtering by contact email).